# Meaning of God's ways

Tags: meaning

The following is from a paragraph in The Hindu.

> In The Wretched of the Earth, which Fanon wrote in the context of the French occupation of Muslim Algeria, he described “the church in the colonies,” as “the white people’s Church, the foreigner’s Church. She does not call the **native to God’s ways but to the ways of the white man, of the master, of the oppressor**.”

What is the meaning of the bold part.

Does it mean, the natives were not according to what the god wanted them to be?

Answer (score 2):

"Native" here mean "native of Algeria". That is an Arabic, or Berber person, born in Algeria, and contrasted with the French people that were colonising Algeria at that time.  (Many people misuse "native" to mean "native English speaker", but that isn't the real meaning)

"She" is the Christian church in Algeria (The Christian community not a particular building). It was common to personify "the church" as female.

"She does not call the native to God ways".  This means that the church does not try to get the Muslims Algerians to act in the way that God/Jesus wants them to act.  Instead, the church tries to get the Muslims to act in the way that French people (who were the cruel and oppressive tyrants) want them to behave.

In short, the church is not promoting God, but promoting French tyranny.

The sentence is about the church, not about the natives.